# AWS EC2 instance role with docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

We are running docker containers in EC2 instance.

When applying IAM role with S3 access it seems that the container cant reach S3

Is there any solution to this kind of problem accept of using ECR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM-docker for this issue, see: https://github.com/swipely/iam-docker

Answer (score -1):

You can try using AWS CLI From Docker to access Bucket.